# React Router Redux, Switch does not consider locationBeforeTransitions

Tags: reactjs, react-router-redux

I had to dig a lot to find this problem.

**Using**:

"history": "^4.6.3",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.5",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",

**And**:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={MyComponent1} />
  <Route path="/route2" component={MyComponent2} />
</Switch>
```

**Facts**:

The Switch component knows nothing about "locationBeforeTransitions". I suppose this object is injected by react-router-redux.

To solve this, I had to pass **locationBeforeTransitions** through mapStateToProps, and...

```
<Switch location={this.props.location} />
```

so my switch component knows what is the current location.

**Two questions**:
1. Why did I had to do this considering react-router-redux should handle this?
2. Is there bether way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

react-router-redux is compatible only with react-router version 2.x and 3.x and you are using React Router v4

It's a new version and they've changed it a lot

> In v4, there is no centralized route configuration. Anywhere that you need to render content based on a route, you will just render a  component.
>   src: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md

I recommend you to stick with v4 and just re-learn it.

Comment: thank you, you answer my first question. I need a code example for my second question.